# G++ `stringop-overread` warning when copying vector into another vector (since G++11)

Tags: c++, g++, gcc-warning

I cannot figure out why the following code is causing this warning:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> Command::rawCommand() const {
    auto rawCommand = std::vector<unsigned char>(1, this->id);
    rawCommand.insert(rawCommand.end(), this->data.begin(), this->data.end());

    return rawCommand;
}
```

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/12/vector:60,
                 from /home/nav/Projects/Bloom/src/DebugToolDrivers/Protocols/CMSIS-DAP/Command.hpp:4,
                 from /home/nav/Projects/Bloom/src/DebugToolDrivers/Protocols/CMSIS-DAP/Command.cpp:1:
In static member function ‘static constexpr _Tp* std::__copy_move<_IsMove, true, std::random_access_iterator_tag>::__copy_m(const _Tp*, const _Tp*, _Tp*) [with _Tp = unsigned char; bool _IsMove = true]’,
    inlined from ‘constexpr _OI std::__copy_move_a2(_II, _II, _OI) [with bool _IsMove = true; _II = unsigned char*; _OI = unsigned char*]’ at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/stl_algobase.h:495:30,
    inlined from ‘constexpr _OI std::__copy_move_a1(_II, _II, _OI) [with bool _IsMove = true; _II = unsigned char*; _OI = unsigned char*]’ at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/stl_algobase.h:522:42,
    inlined from ‘constexpr _OI std::__copy_move_a(_II, _II, _OI) [with bool _IsMove = true; _II = unsigned char*; _OI = unsigned char*]’ at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/stl_algobase.h:529:31,
    inlined from ‘constexpr _OI std::copy(_II, _II, _OI) [with _II = move_iterator<unsigned char*>; _OI = unsigned char*]’ at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/stl_algobase.h:620:7,
    inlined from ‘static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy<true>::__uninit_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator<unsigned char*>; _ForwardIterator = unsigned char*]’ at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:147:27,
    inlined from ‘_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = move_iterator<unsigned char*>; _ForwardIterator = unsigned char*]’ at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:185:15,
    inlined from ‘constexpr _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = move_iterator<unsigned char*>; _ForwardIterator = unsigned char*; _Tp = unsigned char]’ at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:372:37,
    inlined from ‘constexpr _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_move_if_noexcept_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, _Allocator&) [with _InputIterator = unsigned char*; _ForwardIterator = unsigned char*; _Allocator = allocator<unsigned char>]’ at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:397:2,
    inlined from ‘constexpr void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_range_insert(iterator, _ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::forward_iterator_tag) [with _ForwardIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const unsigned char*, std::vector<unsigned char> >; _Tp = unsigned char; _Alloc = std::allocator<unsigned char>]’ at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/vector.tcc:801:9,
    inlined from ‘constexpr void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_insert_dispatch(iterator, _InputIterator, _InputIterator, std::__false_type) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const unsigned char*, std::vector<unsigned char> >; _Tp = unsigned char; _Alloc = std::allocator<unsigned char>]’ at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/stl_vector.h:1779:19,
    inlined from ‘constexpr std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::insert(const_iterator, _InputIterator, _InputIterator) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const unsigned char*, std::vector<unsigned char> >; <template-parameter-2-2> = void; _Tp = unsigned char; _Alloc = std::allocator<unsigned char>]’ at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/stl_vector.h:1481:22,
    inlined from ‘std::vector<unsigned char> Bloom::DebugToolDrivers::Protocols::CmsisDap::Command::rawCommand() const’ at /home/nav/Projects/Bloom/src/DebugToolDrivers/Protocols/CMSIS-DAP/Command.cpp:12:26:
/usr/include/c++/12/bits/stl_algobase.h:431:30: warning: ‘void* __builtin_memmove(void*, const void*, long unsigned int)’ reading 1 or more bytes from a region of size 0 [-Wstringop-overread]
  431 |             __builtin_memmove(__result, __first, sizeof(_Tp) * _Num);
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/12/bits/c++allocator.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/c++/12/bits/allocator.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/12/vector:61:
In member function ‘_Tp* std::__new_allocator<_Tp>::allocate(size_type, const void*) [with _Tp = unsigned char]’,
    inlined from ‘constexpr _Tp* std::allocator< <template-parameter-1-1> >::allocate(std::size_t) [with _Tp = unsigned char]’ at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/allocator.h:183:40,
    inlined from ‘static constexpr _Tp* std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_Up> >::allocate(allocator_type&, size_type) [with _Tp = unsigned char]’ at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/alloc_traits.h:464:28,
    inlined from ‘constexpr std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_allocate(std::size_t) [with _Tp = unsigned char; _Alloc = std::allocator<unsigned char>]’ at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/stl_vector.h:378:33,
    inlined from ‘constexpr void std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_create_storage(std::size_t) [with _Tp = unsigned char; _Alloc = std::allocator<unsigned char>]’ at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/stl_vector.h:395:44,
    inlined from ‘constexpr std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Vector_base(std::size_t, const allocator_type&) [with _Tp = unsigned char; _Alloc = std::allocator<unsigned char>]’ at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/stl_vector.h:332:26,
    inlined from ‘constexpr std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(size_type, const value_type&, const allocator_type&) [with _Tp = unsigned char; _Alloc = std::allocator<unsigned char>]’ at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/stl_vector.h:566:47,
    inlined from ‘std::vector<unsigned char> Bloom::DebugToolDrivers::Protocols::CmsisDap::Command::rawCommand() const’ at /home/nav/Projects/Bloom/src/DebugToolDrivers/Protocols/CMSIS-DAP/Command.cpp:10:65:
/usr/include/c++/12/bits/new_allocator.h:137:55: note: at offset 1 into source object of size 1 allocated by ‘operator new’
  137 |         return static_cast<_Tp*>(_GLIBCXX_OPERATOR_NEW(__n * sizeof(_Tp)));
```

`this->id` is an `unsigned char` and `this->data` is another `std::vector<unsigned char>`.

Oddly, when I reserve the space in the vector, the warning goes away:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> Command::rawCommand() const {
    auto rawCommand = std::vector<unsigned char>(1, this->id);
    rawCommand.reserve(this->data.size() + 1);
    rawCommand.insert(rawCommand.end(), this->data.begin(), this->data.end());

    return rawCommand;
}
```

This warning has only began appearing since G++11. Any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: There may not be anything necessary wrong here. I've observed bogus warnings about potential memory errors from recent versions of gcc, myself. I have one open bug for one of them.

Comment: If you can build this into a [mre] people here can perform magic. And if they can't you'll probably be in great shape to submit a bug report.

Comment: Looks like this bug, though I only saw it appear in gcc 12.  Maybe slightly different conditions, but mostly same stack trace and effect.
https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=107852